# Switch statement not changing for different variables

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, switch-statement

I have the following code:

```
   refreshTableOnTabChange(selectedIndex) {
      console.log("inside refreshTableOnTabChange");
      let level = '';
    //   if (selectedIndex == 1){
    //     this.setState({level: 'day'})
    //     this.setState({tabIndex: 1})
    //     level = 'day';
    //   }
    //   else if (selectedIndex == 2) {
    //     this.setState({level: 'hour'})
    //     this.setState({tabIndex: 2})
    //     level = 'hour';
    //   }
    //   else if (selectedIndex == 3) {
    //     this.setState({level: 'minute'})
    //     this.setState({tabIndex: 3})
    //     level = 'minute';
    //   }
      console.log(selectedIndex);
      switch (selectedIndex) {
          case 1:
            level = 'day';
          case 2:
            level = 'hour';
          case 3:
            level = 'minute';
      }
      console.log(level);
      this.setState({tabIndex: selectedIndex, level: level});
```

after following https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp

I get an odd result, where each time it goes to minute:

[image]

Comment: This the most common `switch` question of all times. You are probably the one billionth person to ask about switch with the answer being "you forgot to use `break`". Congrats, here's your balloon.

Comment: I think I had this problem about 15 years ago @ChrisG. Can I claim a balloon retrospectively? `:-)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use explicitly the statement `break`at the end of each of your cases. Switch statement in JavaScript has a fall through behaviour. As it is stated more formally [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch):

> The optional break statement associated with each case label ensures
>   that the program breaks out of switch once the matched statement is
>   executed and continues execution at the statement following switch. **If**
>   **break is omitted**, the program continues execution at the next
>   statement in the switch statement

So you have to change you switch statement ike below:

```
switch (selectedIndex) {
    case 1:
        level = 'day';
        break;
    case 2:
        level = 'hour';
        break;
    case 3:
        level = 'minute';
        break;
}
```

Comment: Ty. I'm still confused though, why have `case` at all, if matching `case` doesn't end the switch?